# Is http response one element in Observable (Rxjs) stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently expanding my knowledge of RxJs and trying to get better understanding of streams.
I would like to compare Http response to an Observable made by of().

Can we say that JSON response is treated like element 'a' when comparing it to 
`of(['a', 'b', 'c'])` ?
When we get JSON response it's always like getting only one element?

**Is http response one element in Observable stream?**

EDIT:
Obviously, I should have compared it to the first emitted value of interval().

Comment: Http completes when it gets a (finished) http response. Your example btw (of(['a', 'b', 'c'])) is also a ‘single element). It emits the entire array in 1 go.

Comment: you could compare it with of('a')

Comment: @MikeOne Yes. That is true. Obviously. I should have compared it to the first emitted value of interval().. The first value of interval(n) is 1. So I guess when comparing Http resp to interval(), it's like we always get '1' and nothing more..?

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP request using Angular HTTP client is in-fact an RxJS observable of type [`HttpRequest`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L443) that produces a stream of notifications of type [`HttpEvent`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L139). If you wish to see all the notifications, use the option `observe: 'events'` in the request. If this option isn't provided (default), only the last notification (the result from the HTTP request) is returned as seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L503).

From [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress):

> When using `HttpClient.request()` with an HTTP method, configure the
>   method with `observe: 'events'` to see all events, including the
>   progress of transfers.

Seeing this, your example of `of(['a', 'b', 'c'])` isn't similar to a HTTP request since it emits only one notification (the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`) and completes. However `from(['a', 'b', 'c'])` is similar to a HTTP request since it emits each item individually.

> Is HTTP response one element in Observable stream?

Yes, it is the last notification in the stream of notifications. It is of type [`HttpEventType.Response`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L40).

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples-rqbhrr)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({ selector: 'app', templateUrl: 'app.component.html' })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  events = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {observe: 'events'}).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      this.events.push(event);
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
}
```

Console output
[image]

`type: 0` corresponds to `HttpEventType.Sent` and `type: 4` corresponds to `HttpEventType.Response`. You could possibly see more events in a more complicated request (eg. a video upload request).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a really good, explaining answer.